# button cant draw rectangle vb.net

Tags: vb.net, button, draw

I'm trying to draw a rectangle by clicking a button, however as simple as I thought it would be I can't get it right.

```
Private Sub Button36_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button36.Click
    ' Create pen. 
    Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 1)

    ' Create rectangle. 
    Dim rect As New Rectangle(10, 710, 35, 100)

    ' Draw rectangle to screen.
    Me.CreateGraphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, rect)
End Sub
```

I'm using VB.NET

Comment: You should name your buttons.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Using CreateGraphics() is almost never correct, whatever you draw will disappear again when the form repaints itself.  The likely "it doesn't work" explanation here is that your window isn't big enough.  Use a value less than 710.  Minimize and restore the window to see the problem with CreateGraphics().

Answer (score 2):

You need to do all of your drawing inside the `Paint` event.
Otherwise, Windows will erase everything next time the form repaints.

Add a handler for the `Paint` event and draw everything inside using `e.Graphics`.
You will need to keep track of what needs to get painted at all times.

Comment: Use the Graphics supplied in the Paint() event via `e.Graphics`.  *I've actually seen people take the advice above and then proceed to use CreateGraphics() from within the Paint() event...